# Parenthetical citation without author's name (\parencite*{}) not working in biblatex-chicago with [notes] style

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am using `biblatex-chicago` in the notes style. Sometimes I want to use the `\parencite*` command in a footnote, so as to produce, say:

> Thomas S. Kuhn (*The Copernican Revolution: Planetary Astronomy in the Development of  Western Thought* [1957; Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, 1995]) wrote that...

The documentation for the `biblatex-chicago` package does not mention this case (parenthetical citation without author while using the notes style), but in the documentation of the `biblatex` package, it is said about `\parencite*` (p. 80):

> This command is provided by all author-year and author-title styles.
>   It is similar to the regular `\parencite` command but merely prints the
>   year or the title, respectively.

However, I cannot get it to work with the `biblatex-chicago` notes style. Instead, I get the full citation with the author's name, even if I use the starred (*) option of the command. This is a minimal working example (I compile using XeLaTeX) that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[notes,strict,isbn=false,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,hyperref=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document} 

Thomas S.\ Kuhn \parencite*{Kuhn19571995TheCopernicanRevolution} wrote that\ldots

\end{document}
```

The contents of `bibliography.bib` being:

```
@book{Kuhn19571995TheCopernicanRevolution,
author = {Kuhn, {Thomas S.}},
title = {The Copernican Revolution},
subtitle = {Planetary Astronomy in the Development of Western Thought},
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
address = {Cambridge, Mass.},
date = {1995},
origdate = {1957}
}
```

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `biblatex-chicago`, the `\cite*` commands turn off *ibidem*-tracker ([see § 4.3.2 of the `biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf)) while in the standard `biblatex` styles `\cite*` has exactly the behaviour you expect ([see § 3.7.2 of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

**NB**: the solutions here are quite hacky - especially the one for fullcite - maybe you could contact the maintainer and ask him to incorporate this feature, in the meantime use this solution with care.

To achieve the behaviour you expect, we will need to modify the `biblatex-chicago` styles quite heavily.

Copy `biblatex-chicago.sty`, `chicago-notes.bbx` and `chicago-notes.cbx` to a location where `latex` can find them and rename them to, let's say, `biblatex-chicago-na.sty`, `chicago-notes-na.bbx` and `chicago-notes-na.cbx` respectively.

---

First, we modify `biblatex-chicago-na.sty`. Just add

```
\DeclareOption{notes-na}{\def\cms@style{notesna}}
```

after `\DeclareOption{notes}{\def\cms@style{notes}}` (l. 21).

Then add

```
\def\cms@notesna{%
  \RequirePackage[style=chicago-notes-na]{biblatex}%
  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    pagetracker=true,autocite=footnote,abbreviate=false,alldates=comp,
    citetracker=true,ibidtracker=constrict,usetranslator=true,
    usecompiler=true,loccittracker=constrict,dateabbrev=false,
    maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sorting=\cms@choose,sortcase=false}}
```

to line 68, somewhere after the block `\def\cms@notesna{......}`.

---

We now modify `chicago-notes-na.cbx`.
Add

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:noauth}{%
   \ifciteseen%
     {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
        {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
           {\usebibmacro{cite:noauth:ibid}}%
           {\global\toggletrue{cms@shortnote}%
             \global\togglefalse{cms@fullnote}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:noauth:short}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}%
        {\iftoggle{cms@shorthandibid}%
          {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:noauth:ibid}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}%
     {\iftoggle{cms@allshort}%
       {\global\toggletrue{cms@shortnote}%
         \global\togglefalse{cms@fullnote}%
         \global\toggletrue{cms@printshhand}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:noauth:short}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:save}}%
       {\global\toggletrue{cms@fullnote}%
         \global\togglefalse{cms@shortnote}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:noauth:full}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}}%
```

after the block from `\newbibmacro*{cite}{...}` (around line 260).

Finally, add the following block of code.

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:noauth:full}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewbibmacro{author/editor}{}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}\frenchspacing}
      {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}%
   \iffieldundef{shorthand}
     {}%
     {\usebibmacro{cms:shorthandintro}}}%
  \endgroup}

\newbibmacro*{cite:noauth:short}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@allshort}%
    or
    test {\ifbibliography}
  }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
  {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}%:\thefield{entrytype}?

\newbibmacro*{cite:noauth:ibid}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@noibid}
  {\global\toggletrue{cms@shortnote}%
    \global\togglefalse{cms@fullnote}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:noauth:short}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:save}}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@allshort}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
    \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cms@loccit}}%
    {}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitena}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:noauth}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

You should also change the macro `newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}` to (I've added two `%`s so there is not spurious white space in `\parencite` with ibidem)

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@noibid}
  {\global\toggletrue{cms@shortnote}%
    \global\togglefalse{cms@fullnote}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:short}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:save}}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@allshort}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
    \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cms@loccit}}%
    {}}}
```

---

You then use the modified style like this `\usepackage[notes-na,strict,isbn=false,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,hyperref=true]{biblatex-chicago-na}`, the new command is `\parencitena{...}`.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes-na,strict,isbn=false,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,hyperref=true]{biblatex-chicago-na}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{KuhnCopRev,
  author    = {Thomas S. Kuhn},
  title     = {The Copernican Revolution},
  subtitle  = {Planetary Astronomy in the Development of Western Thought},
  publisher = {Harvard University Press},
  address   = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  date      = {1995},
  origdate  = {1957}
}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  %author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter and Rita Esearcher and Steven C. Ientist and Stuart T. Udent and Peter R. Ofessor and Lewis E. C. Turer},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  page          = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
}
@online{testonline,
  author        = {Bernie Logger},
  title         = {A Very Opinionated Blog Post},
  url           = {http://example.com},
  year          = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  Thomas S. Kuhn \parencitena{KuhnCopRev} told us that \ldots
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that solution. However, since as you say, it's pretty hacky, do you think it would be simpler to make a new cite command, that would print [author] ([title])? That is, author's name first (short or long form depending on whether or not is the first occurrence) and then title in parenthesis (short or long form as the case with the author)? I'm an illiterate when it comes to programming, but perhaps that would be a technically more simple solution? What do you think? Otherwise, I will use this solution. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mårten Your new cite command would be as hacky to realise as this one, I believe - it might even be harder because one cannot simply use a parencite template. The *really* hacky bit of the solution above is the way the first (full) citation is handled, the rest is pretty standard stuff, it just appears hacky since one has to modify quite a bit of code to get it working (I was not too keen to overwrite commands, so had to provide new ones).