# Biblatex-chicago style - parencite or similar option?

Tags: biblatex

I am currently switching to the chicago citation style due to how the assignments are being done. That meant I needed to use the biblatex-chicago package which I thought worked great in the start, but after a bit of troubleshooting I couldn't not find the answer of why it is doing this.

The problem is, if I cite an author more than once with `\parencite[page][author]` it works fine the first time, next time it just returns the page in parenthesis. I've tried almost every option in the documentation.

This is my current package options

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    authordate,
    sorting=ynt,
    isbn=false,
    hyperref=true,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    sortcites=true]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Is it normal behavior for this style or am I missing something? I've (tried) attached a small MWE here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,oneside,british,a4paper]{memoir}

%  Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    loccittracker=true,
    abbreviate=false,
    citetracker=false,
    authordate,
    sorting=ynt,
    isbn=false,
    hyperref=true,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    sortcites=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{Me}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

test \parencite[539]{LConsoli2006}  and then \parencite[540]{LConsoli2006}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `biblatex` option `hyperref=true,` is usually not more useful than the default `hyperref=auto,`. Both settings will produce links if and only if `hyperref` is loaded. The only difference is that `hyperref=true,` will throw a warning when `hyperref` is not loaded, `hyperref=auto,` will not produce a warning in that case. I would drop `hyperref=true,` here (you even have it twice). `sorting=ynt,` will give you a sorting result that is probably incompatible with the expected CMoS bibliography sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you always find the answer when you've posted and sat with it for a long time.

I am so sorry for the inconvenience.

The answer to this problem was *simply* to add `ibidtracker=false`as an option. I also found great resource from this answer [By moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132013/256344) (thanks!).

Answer (score 0):

`biblatex-chicago` has an option called `noibid` to disable the style's *ibidem* feature. It works on a slightly different level than just disabling the tracker, but should in principle produce the same output.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,oneside,british,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  authordate,
  noibid,
  sorting=ynt,
  sortcites=true
  abbreviate=false,
  citetracker=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
test \parencite[539]{sigfridsson}  and then \parencite[540]{sigfridsson}

\end{document}
```

[image: test (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 539) and then (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 540)]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70738/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129487/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301475/35864.